# Representation theory of 3-step nilpotent finite groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

I am interested in understanding the representation theory of certain finite nilpotent groups (over the complex numbers). The groups $G$ of interest have the following properties:

1) G is $3$-step nilpotent finite group

2) G is a $2$-group

3) G is an extension of a 2-step nilpotent group H, by $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

I know that the irreducible representations of a finite nilpotent group are monomial, and there is a uniform construction of these representations in the case of $2$-step nilpotent groups. For a $2$-step nilpotent group $H$, each irreducible representation $\rho$ of $H$ of dimension greater than $1$ is induced from a character of a fixed maximal abelian subgroup $S$ of $H$. In fact $\rho$ is determined by its central character.

Question:

What can be said about the representation theory of $G$? Can we identify a minimal set of the subgroups that can be used to construct each irreducible representation as a monomial representation? (For example, for a $2$-step nilpotent group we need a maximal abelian subgroup and the group itself.)

I would appreciate any thoughts on this question, any references on 1-3 above.  That is, any references on the representation theory of $3$-step nilpotent groups, $2$-groups, or two-fold extensions of $2$-step nilpotent group, or any combination thereof.

Sincerely,

Moshe

Comment: An extension of $A$ by $B$ has two possible meanings (is $A$ the kernel or the quotient? unfortunately both conventions are widely used).

Comment: Apologies.  An extension of $A$ by $B$ means that $A$ is the quotient.